# Error Quandl Fetching Data

Tags: r, quandl

I am having error fetching data from Quandl via R. Any have any idea what this means?

```
require(Quandl)
Quandl("ICE/BF2002")


Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Comment: Can't confirm. The Quandl command does not throw any error on my computer and it downloads the requested data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think i found the answer (although i do not understand it).

if you get that error run this before hand:

```
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was facing the very same problem. This solution has solved my problem.